# Wordpress - Transfer Woocomerce product name to Contact form after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

http://skifimba.hostfree.pw/

This is my website. I'm noob in php/js and I want the following thing:

On the page I have added Request button (woocommerce) for products and when it's clicked a Contact form pops up. I want to echo the product name in `<p></p>` tags in the contact form. Anyone have an idea how this can be done?

Button locations

[First button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stc2a.png)

[Second button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPVCZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a click handler on the request button, find the text of the 'h3', and set the modal form's "name" field value to that.

Take this JavaScript for example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // When the Request button is clicked
    $('.request-form-btn').on('click', function(){
        // Set 'title' to the closest product's h3 text
        var title = $(this).closest('.prod-i').find('h3').text();

        // Set the value of the "name" field to the title we got above.
        $('[name="modal_name"]').val( title );
    });
});
```

It appears you're using a premium theme, so add this to the "Custom/Body/Footer" scripts section of the website if there is one, otherwise you'll need to use one of the many "Header/Footer" script plugins that are available.

You can test this by pasting the JavaScript into the dev tools console on that page.

Comment: It doesn't work on the product page though

[http://skifimba.hostfree.pw/shop/skuteri/garelli-gsp-50/

Comment: It seems I got it working somehow. The only place left now is when the magnifier button is clicked comes a popup: https://i.imgur.com/zU7M7bB.png

I can't get it to work there.

My current JS code is: http://jsfiddle.net/w65pucL7/

I'm so sorry for the spam.

Comment: Looks like the parent container is `.prod-cont` not `.prodcont` - that should fix your issue

Comment: Tried it, it returns empty value.